# Bash Scripting - REGEX to dump a file list

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I have 4 files extensions as result of previous works, stored in the $SEARCH array, as follows  :

```
declare -a SEARCH=("toggled" "jtr" "jtr.toggled" "cupp")
```

I want to issue one file list for each of the 4 above extension patterns, as follows, except for the case with 2 dots and 2 extensions (marked "NO") :

```
################################################################################
1 - SEARCH FOR toggled in /media
regex   : ([^\/]+)(\.)(toggled)$
command : find /media -type f | grep --color -P ([^\/]+)(\.)(toggled)$
################################################################################
/media/myfile_1.jtr.toggled --> NO
/media/myfile_1.toggled
/media/myfile_2.jtr.toggled --> NO
/media/myfile_2.toggled
/media/myfile_3.jtr.toggled --> NO
/media/myfile_3.toggled


################################################################################
2 - SEARCH FOR jtr in /media
regex   : ([^\/]+)(\.)(jtr)$
command : find /media -type f | grep --color -P ([^\/]+)(\.)(jtr)$
################################################################################
/media/myfile_1.jtr
/media/myfile_2.jtr
/media/myfile_3.jtr


################################################################################
3 - SEARCH FOR jtr.toggled in /media
regex   : ([^\/]+)(\.)(jtr.toggled)$
command : find /media -type f | grep --color -P ([^\/]+)(\.)(jtr.toggled)$
################################################################################
/media/myfile_1.jtr.toggled
/media/myfile_2.jtr.toggled
/media/myfile_3.jtr.toggled


################################################################################
4 - SEARCH FOR cupp in /media
regex   : ([^\/]+)(\.)(cupp)$
command : find /media -type f | grep --color -P ([^\/]+)(\.)(cupp)$
################################################################################
/media/myfile_1.cupp
/media/myfile_2.cupp
/media/myfile_3.cupp
```

Obviously I spent hours on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oK0eO2/2) w/o success.
I also tried to achieve my target with other methods, which does not fit with the rest of the code.

Here is a code extract :

```
for ext in "${SEARCH[@]}"
do

    COUNTi=$((COUNTi+1))

    REGEX="([^\/]+)(\.)("$ext")$" #
    # Ideally, the Regex should come from a pattern array

    printf '%*s' "$len" | tr ' ' "$mychar"
    echo -e "\n$COUNTi - SEARCH FOR $ext in $BASEDIR"
    echo "regex   : $REGEX"
    echo "command : find $BASEDIR -type f | grep --color -P $REGEX"
    printf '%*s' "$len" | tr ' ' "$mychar" && echo

    find $BASEDIR -type f | grep --color -P $REGEX 
    # the Regex caveats as the double dot extensions are not parsed correctly.

    echo -e "\n"

done
```

So my 2 questions related to the same piece of code  :

1. REGEX : what would be a correct regex, to be able to parse and dump the files by extension family (pls see the 4 SEARCH patterns and related dumps) ?
2. ARRAYS : Once above point is solved, how to use a pattern array data, containing the $extension placeholder, into the looped REGEX ?

   ```
    PATTERN+=( "([^\/]+)(\.)($ext)$" )
   # All of these below : CAVEATS escaping $ or not...
   # REGEX=${PATTERN[5]}
   # REGEX=$(eval "${PATTERN[5]}" )
   # echo "pattern : ${PATTERN[5]}"
   # eval "$REGEX=\$REGEX"
   # eval "$REGEX=\"\$REGEX\""
   # REGEX=$(echo "${REGEX}")
   # REGEX=${!PATTERN[5]}
   ```

Notes:
I read all regex documentations for hours, tried hundreds of regex patterns, w/o success as I can't understand these   regex rationales.
I also  tried other ways, for example `find / -name "sayONEnameinmysearchpattern" ! -iname "theothernamesfromtehsearchpattern"`. This is not what I'm looking for.

Thx

Comment: Will there ever be '.' characters in the name of a .toggled file?

Comment: @Will Barnwell : Yes. The pattern will keep as mentioned.

Comment: I meant, will there ever be a file like abc.defg.toggled that you want in the .toggled list?

Comment: @Will Barnwell : Sorry I did not get it. No, I will not have files with abc.def.toggled. Only abc.toggled and abc.jtr.toggled, plus jtr and  cupp files.

Comment: then modify the first part of your regex to match all characters except slashes and dots `[^\/.]`, then .jtr.toggled files will not appear in the .toggled list

Comment: I forgot to mention that the regex is PCRE and not POSIX,  since I'm piping `find` with  `grep -P`.

Comment: It does not work as expected : when I list the files with the "toggled" pattern, I don't want to list the files abc.jtr.toggled but only the files abc.toggled

Comment: your problem is the file extensions overlap, there is no generic way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the REGEX line in your code to:

```
REGEX='^(.*\/|)[^\/\.]+\.'"$ext\$"
```

The perl regular expression to match the basename of the file is in single quotes.  This prevents the shell from trying to expand it.  The $ext is in double quotes, so it will be expanded by the shell.  The trailing $ is escaped with a backslash just for form.

The leading ^(.*/|) will match a leading directory (ending with /), the [^/\.]+ will match one or more characters that are NOT '.' or '/'.  That must then be followed by a '.' and your extension, followed by the end of the file name ($) to match.

The key here is to anchor your match at both ends (^ and $) and not allow any dots '.' except the ones you really want.

You also might want to put $REGEX in quotes... "$REGEX" in the grep command near the end of your code extract.

Comment: Thx, works like a charm. Now reading your crystal clear explanation. Thx again.